# How can i use column value filter in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the below script for import data from another google sheet, how can I add a column value filter in it.

```js
function muscriptedimortrange2() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1-fj1z1gxdow5Et031Bty9CXDoCFwsrLdYcFkiJ-6BWQ")
    .getSheetByName("URN")
    .getRange("A1:J")
    .getValues();
  var syst = new Date();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("REV")
    .getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("REV")
    .getRange(1, 30, 1, 1)
    .setValue(syst);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `a column value filter in it`? Please add some sample input data and the expected result.

Comment: Here i want to add filter with Column E, which has state names, filter needs to be added as "Delhi"

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function

```js
function muscriptedimortrange2() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1-fj1z1gxdow5Et031Bty9CXDoCFwsrLdYcFkiJ-6BWQ")
    .getSheetByName("URN")
    .getRange("A1:J")
    .getValues();
  
  // Here is the filter
  values = values.filter(row => row[4] === "Delhi")

  var syst = new Date();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("REV")
    .getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("REV")
    .getRange(1, 30, 1, 1)
    .setValue(syst);
}
```

To use the filter function you need to provide a callback that evaluates some condition. In your case it is `row[4] === "Delhi"`. `row[4]` corresponds to column E. If the result of the callback is `true` then the row is included, else it is discarded.